Burp does not intercept request via Chrome
I thought I had everything in place to use Burp Proxy with Chrome on MacOS

Burp Suite -> Proxy settings is defaulted (127.0.0.1:8080) + Intercept is on


Proxy is enabled in System Settings (MacOS)



Bypass proxy settings:
*.local,169.254/16

CA certificate is added via Chrome
a) Download CA Certificate http://burpsuite/
b) Add and trust it on MacOS



In Chrome I have when proxy is enabled
Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from portswigger.net (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
To get Chrome’s highest level of security, turn on enhanced protection



May be Chrome rejects the proxy CA because it is not ia Certificate Transparency CA? After switching to Burp have you cleared browser cache to make sure there are no pinned certificates left?
